Reduced resource consumption for ModSecurity
I recently learned and implemented ModSecurity with the OWASP CRS rule set. I am implementing ModSec integration on Nginx in a K8s environment. The problem I encountered was that the ModSec integration caused the Nginx pod to consume a lot of CPU and RAM. If there are a large number of requests (about 100,000 requests), CPU consumption can go up to 2 cores and RAM can go up to 2GB per pod.
I'm just using some rules related to SQLi and XSS, LFI.
I tried the configuration according to ModSecurity Performance Recommendations
but the result still does not reduce resource consumption too much.
Can someone tell me how to configure ModSec to reduce resource consumption? I would like each of my pods to only consume about 1 core and less than 2GB of RAM.
We look forward to your help and sincerely thank everyone for their comments!


Can someone tell me how to configure ModSec to reduce resource consumption?

Unfortunately there is no any chance to configure ModSecurity to reduce resource consumption. What I can say is that 2 core (you didn't mention the types of core) and the 2GB of RAM seem very low for 100,000 requests (per second, I assume). That's lot of transactions, and each transaction uses lot of memory.
You can tune your instance (that the blog post mentions too) that which types of files should be inspected, then you can decrease the resources usage, but I'm afraid that's only a partial solution. Create a filter for this based on the file suffix is very risky IMHO, so be careful with that.

Thank you for your comment. Sorry for not being specific about my testing, I sent requests using the BurpSuite Intruder tool with 100,000 POST/GET requests (time depends on server processing speed, not seconds).
In the blog post I mentioned, I configured SecResponseBodyAccess Off and also configured the concurrent logging mechanism. I haven't seen much performance improvement when configuring with those options. Have you tried configuring those options?

In case of libmodsecurity3 (which used by Nginx) if you turn off SecResponseBodyAccess, then you completely turn off phase:3 and phase:4. It's on purpose (by design), but it's a bug and we need to fix that in the future. Depending on your rule set it has to provide a better performance. Turning logs can also help the performance. But 2GB RAM won't enough for 100000 req/sec. It's a fact.

Thank @airween. It seems quite difficult to limit Nginx ModSec's resource usage to a specific level. I'm also looking for a solution to send logs to remote systems. Previously I knew about mlogc combined with concurrent log ModSec but it seems this tool is no longer being developed. Do you have any suggestions to help me?

As I know Nginx can send logs through syslog to everywhere, see this article: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/

Thank you very much @airween, I will experiment further with your suggestion. Hopefully in the future ModSecurity will be further optimized when integrating with Nginx.
